# Is it okay to use PhP include() in body of basic page?

Tags: 7

Aside from the usual warnings about using PhP, which I understand and am taking seriously, is there any drawback to using the PhP include() function in the "Body" box of the "Edit Basic page" form?

This is not for users of the site. This is only for me, the creator of the site. No one else will have permission to use PhP code on the site.

The reason I want to do this is as follows: I'm revamping an ASP site into Drupal. I have a page that builds its contents from a large amount of data drawn from a database (which I've imported from Access into MySQL). I'm going to translate the Javascript of the ASP page into PhP to do this in Drupal. But I'm getting tired of working in that little and unintelligent "Body" box in the "Edit Basic page" form. If I just put an include() in that box, then I can work on the PhP code in a file in NotePad++. Then every time I save a change to that file, I can test the effect by just refreshing the page.

Any reason not to work that way?

Comment: I am not sure why you would translate JavaScript to PHP when Drupal uses JavaScript too.

Comment: I think there is already a question about why using the PHP filter is a bad practice, which answers this question too.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - This is really interesting. After I got two really helpful answers, you disabled answering because you deem the question not susceptible to being properly answered. Then you add a comment with some additional helpful information for me that I didn't know. In any case, I'm really glad you waited until after AyeshK and tunic posted their answers before you disabled answering.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - You think there is such a question? I did a search before posting my question. If my question is redundant with an answered question, could you please post a link to it?

Comment: This question is too broad, even if you get two answers. I don't get why you worry about using PHP in a node body, when you will be the only one accessing the site.

Comment: I won't be the only one accessing the site. I'm the only one who will have access to develop that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to your reply in the comments, I thought to post an answer instead.

There are many reasons why it's not OK to embed executable code where we expect to have actual content. This is not Drupal specific. It's not even PHP specific ([this one](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval) on JS for example).

Since you indicate you are comfortable writing PHP code, why not create a new module instead, and put your code (that you expect to put in the Body) inside the module? You'll be taking a big step in the Drupal learning curve too. It's not that hard to write a simple module!

As for Drupal, the reason is because your PHP code is interpreted very lately, or sometimes, it will not be executed at all. PHP code is executed from the `PHP Filter`, which is only run when you output the code with this filters processed. You can **easily** break your PHP snippet:

- Run some Rules on the Body content (such as a string match). Rules will match the raw PHP content: Not what you expect it to be.
- Email: Modules such as Notifications, Mime Mail can apply different filters on your content (other than PHP Filter), which will make the email content will contain the raw PHP content.
- Views: Filter rewrite features will process and output your raw PHP content.

Other than the above, you are making your core logic **not controllable by version control systems** we have (git for example). It's always easy to keep them in mind, but once you are done with the site and move on, your Neurons do funny things and forget the fact that you have some core logic embed somewhere (is it node 134, 314 or 420?) in the `field_data_body.body_value` column.

**When it's barely acceptable to use PHP in the database?**

Admittedly, there are some situations that we have to use some small PHP snippet here are there to save time creating whole new plugins.

**Views:** Views contextual filters support evaluating some PHP snippet to validate contextual filters.

**Rule:** Rules conditions and actions have "Execute PHP" as an action/condition.

I think above two cases are barely acceptable cases that you can use some PHP. This is because you are supposed to put some PHP code there, and the parent code that evaluates the PHP snippet is well aware that it contains some PHP code. If a field description says "Do *not* use ", that means the field is aware that the input contains some PHP.

**Modules are safe?**

To address your comment to this question, you can use PHP in the module because, well, that is where you code your logic. A malicious snippet is equally harmful regardless where you put it. But when you have it in a module, you can turn it off, other developers know that you put custom code here, and it can be versioned.

Modules are the basic logic behind the entire site. Nodes, user accounts, taxonomy, menu, blocks, they all are modules themselves. Your custom module is equally good enough to implement same hooks. 
You can only put PHP code where you are asked (Views execute PHP fields, Node content, etc). But with a module, you become your own god that you can implement any hook you want, and have a far wider access to the system.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed mind transfer! You've given me some persuasive reasons that my approach is wrong. I've been telling myself not to allow myself to delay getting the sites up by getting distracted with developing modules. You've got me reconsidering that. I'm going to take a look and see what it might mean when you say "not too hard to write a simple module." In the meantime, can you say, why is it okay to have PhP in a module and not in the "Body" box? (I feel like that's got to be a stupid question, but I guess I'm just still that stupid on Drupal.)

Comment: Please see updated answer.

Comment: Would your warnings about putting PHP code on a page also apply to putting PHP code in a custom token inserted in a page by the modules "Custom tokens" and "Token filter"? "Custom tokens" does not evaluate PHP in its tokens, but passes the PHP directly to the page via "Token filter" so the page has to use a text filter that allows PHP code. Is that dangerous? Does it depend on whether the token are just little snippets or longer chunks of code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But if your `PHP Filter` (which executes the PHP) is executed after token replacements, then it's good as other PHP code. 
Also, I don't see a reason to use tokens inside PHP. In most cases, the stuff that you want to use are available as PHP variables (`$node`, `$argument`, `$view`, `$row`, etc are some examples).

Comment: First thing I'm using this for is links between sites in multi-site setup. In development, I need the links to go to local URL. Online, the links have to go to online URLs. My local URLs look like "http://site1.local", "http://site2.local", etc. With custom tokens, I was able to enter links to site1 on the other sites using a token whose content is <code><?php return("http://" . (substr(token_replace("[site:url]"), -7) == ".local/" ? "site1.local" : "www.site1.com")); ?></code>. This solved a huge problem that was easy in my ASP pages, but I didn't know how to do in Drupal -- until now. Is ok?

Comment: Well, you could easily build links and URLs with `l()` and `url()` functions. So much easier than tinkering with tokens.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you only want to debug a certain code, so you exeute the code inside the node only temporary. I think for that task is much better to just edit the code in your favorite editor wrapped in a function and then call it inside a `/devel/php` page.

For example:

```
function my_code() {

   // Experimental code here.
}
```

Then goto `/devel/php` with [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) enabled and complete the textarea with:

```
my_experimental_code();
```

You can edit your code and go to the browser window and push 'Execute'. You can use `dpm()` function to show data on the screen. See results, then modifiy your code and then you only have to go to the browser again and just click 'Execute' again.

Comment: Oh boy, in addition to not wanting to get into writing modules right away, I've also been carefully avoid downloading any modules until I really understand why I need them. Looks like I need to make this the first module I download. (If I could accept more than one answer, I'd accept this one as well. Thank you for your help.)

Comment: I wish you good luck, @NewSites on your first module. There are some modules, such as the Devel module, that can help you i your journey. Also look at the examples module (http://drupal.org/project/examples) for some decent code to inspire.

Comment: Drupal is modular, you almost always need to download modules to extend funcitonality. In fact is recommended to use a ctrontibuted module instead of writting your own (because a contrib module is more tested than own code). About answers: you can't accept two answers but you can upvote any answer if the answer is useful.